# When I 'improve [an] edit' suggested by a <2k user, do they still get +2 reputation?

Tags: support

As of today I am allowed to review suggested edits ^_^

I'm reading lots of posts here to help me do a good job.

I can be absent-minded and I'm certainly not immune to typos, bad formatting decisions, or omissions myself, but when reviewing I am doing my best to be focused and critical, so I am likely to spot some further improvement and select 'improve edit' even to make minor changes (I might even fix a [comma splice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice).)

I'm talking about cases where the suggested edit was helpful, and I want to give credit to the person who suggested it, so I want to make sure they still get +2 reputation for editing, so they know their editing is appropriate.

Does the suggester still get +2 if I 'improve' their edit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if you choose "improve" then the system first accepts the original edit and awards the +2 and then applies yours on top of it. That's why it's your name that's shown as the last editor.

If you check the edit history, you'll see the edit you approved just before yours and if you go to that editor's profile, you'll see the +2. [Here's an example](https://askubuntu.com/posts/796929/revisions) where I did this. You can see both the edit I approved and mine appearing at the same time (hover over the date shown and you'll see they both came through in the same second).

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation & example :)